# Testing a shell script on AIX

Tags: aix

I develop a POSIX shell script to check SSL certificates and connections.

The script is not running on AIX and I would like to see if I can adapt it.

Is there a free (or cheap way) to get a shell account on an AIX machine to test an open source project?

Comment: I doubt it, but you could quote your script (or the relevant parts of it).

Comment: It's 5'000 LoC ... (the issue is here https://github.com/matteocorti/check_ssl_cert/issues/306)

Comment: `mktemp(1)` doesn't exist in default AIX distribution, so it should be added to the documentation that it has to be installed from GNU!coreutils and put on the PATH

Comment: I know, and I could implement a workaround, but I suspect other issues with the script. If I could test it on my own it would avoid a ping-pong with the person which issued the ticket.

Comment: There are several other issues with sed, file, grep and date

Comment: Anyways, `sed -E` is the next problem: AIX!sed doesn't have such option. Same for `grep -m` and `date -j`

Answer (score 0):

A relatively cheap way to get a shell account on an AIX machine would be https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free.

It looks like it's free for limited use.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really find an option to get an account for less than 100$.